# Strange HttpClient logging of end request long before GetAsync is finished

Tags: c#, http, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

I make some HTTP requests to REST API that returns quite a lot of data (around 100 MB). I have now used `HttpClientFactory` from .Net Core to get the data and it works fine. But what has puzzled me is a discrepancy between my timing and internal timing that comes from the library itself.

Here is an example message from the library:

> End processing HTTP request after 130311.0094ms - OK

The thing is: it really takes 20-30 more seconds to really download all the data even though the library has written it's all finished (To execute `client.GetAsync()` method).

I assume what happens here is that library is very eager to report right after the header is received without waiting for the body to get downloaded.

This really sound like a bug, but I am not sure if it is. Maybe someone has a better explanation on why this is happening?

P.S. Here is an example of my code:

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
var response = await Client.GetAsync(url);
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
```

Elapsed time in my log is way higher than in the system message

P.P.S I have tried running with `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead` but it really did not change the outcome, it's still a big difference.

Comment: please  provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's quite a theoretical question, so there is no need for an example here, since I am not asking on how to improve the code or find a bug in my code.

Comment: stack overflow is not good for theoretical questions.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question on how the library works even though there is no code to provide, I don't really understand this attitude on why should this question be closed.

Comment: perhaps theres swapping going on. its hard to tell without how you are writing your code.

Comment: @DanielA.White I have added the example thought it's really not much and I doubt it could help...

Comment: how big is the response?

Comment: It is around 100 Mb, I have added it to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/15375507/507793, look up `client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);`

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but thanks for a useful link! It's probably the answer really there though: HttpCompletionOption makes it behave this way.

Comment: Check the network traffic with Fiddler, or with F12 of Chrome/Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is how middleware in `HttpClient` works that is used by logging framework. Loading of body happens for some reason outside the pipeline, so logging always happens right after headers are received.

More details in this [question](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1121) on github.